# Theory on creating custom UI framework

Tags: user-interface, architecture, frameworks

I was wondering if anyone knows a good book or series of articles I can read to get familiar with UI framework internals and how they are created?

Something around MVVM would be nice. To be precise, I want to know exactly how UI framework is being made from scratch.

It includes layouts, controls, rendering (drawing pixels or rendering into other language like HTML), interactions among all these elements, etc.

Any information regarding this is helpful!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Prism 4](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/).  It's an MVVM UI framework.  Also, the [Prism 4 developers guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) is the best reference on MVVM that I have found yet.

It is an excellent guide, even if you do not use prism, as it covers MVVM concepts such as using commands, handling dialog requests (interactions), and inter-viewmodel communication in depth.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. Though I gave MVVM just as an example. For me more important are the internals of a framework and not the architectural pattern itself :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at this MIX presentation [Build Your Own MVVM Framework](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/EX15).  It's from the author of the Caliburn MVVM framework.